# ado.net Closing Connection when using "using" statement

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I am doing my database access methods to SQL Server like this

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//connection string)
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcname, con))
     {
       try{
           con.open();
           //data reader code
       }
       catch
       {

       }
     }
  }
```

Do I need to be closing or disposing of SqlCommand, or will the using statement take care of that for me? I just don't want connection hanging open 
Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `using` will take care of it for you.  Under the hood, `SqlConnection.Dispose()` calls the `SqlConnection.Close()` method, and `SqlCommand.Dispose()` calls `SqlCommand.Close()`.

As additional background, a `using` statement is syntactic sugar for a `try ... finally` that disposes the `IDisposable` object in the `finally`.

Comment: It will take care of it - but I would still close it explicitly and use the using() block only as a "backup" for when I forget.

Comment: Great Thank you! Thanks to everyone who responded as well!

Comment: Relying on such 'features' can be dangerous, and confusing. I would still close it explicitly, just as marc_s. TBH, I would dispose it explicitly, as well, and only at the place I would want it disposed.

Answer (score 12):

As an aside, you can make the code more concise and readable as follows:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*connection string*/))
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcname, con))
 {
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

As Phil said, the using clause will take care of it for you.  When compiled down it wraps the connection create in a try .. finally and places the connection disposal call inside the finally.

For more information you can see the [using statement article at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Yes your code will close the connection, however that typcally means release back to the connection pool to be truely closed later.

If you execute this snippet of code, and then do an sp_who and observe that your connection is still there, that would be why.

If you absolutely need the connection truely closed (an edge case to be sure) then use the [ClearAllPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx)
static method of ths SqlConnection

Answer (score 2):

`Using` keyword will automatically close the connection for you
so you don't need to worry about calling `connection.close()` at the end every time.

Comment: I don't quite see, how this differs from the accepted answer. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

when the scope

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//connection string) 
{
}
```

will over , connection will automatically be disposed by runtime. so don't worry

Answer (score 0):

I think "using" was not required for SqlCommand. "Using" for SqlConnection would have done the job for you alone.
In fact you connection is submitted to Connection pool.

Comment: No - you need using() for every disposable object - `using(SqlConnection.....)` alone won't take care of your `SqlCommand`

Comment: Anything that implements IDisposable should be placed in a using statement.  It's good practice to be able to quickly see code that just isn't right.