# Why does this UPDATE command not update the data, even though there is no error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `users` table having fields `uname`, `ushortname` and `pswd` as well `ucode` as primary key.
The following `UPDATE` is not working:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string uname = Request.QueryString["uname"];
        string ucode = Request.QueryString["ucode"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uname))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from users WHERE ucode=@ucode", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            conn.Open();
            txtUserName.ReadOnly = false;
            txtUserShortName.ReadOnly = false;
            txtPassword.ReadOnly = false;
            dadapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ucode", ucode));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                LblUcode.Text = dr["ucode"].ToString();
                txtPassword.Text=dr["pswd"].ToString();
                txtUserShortName.Text = dr["ushortname"].ToString();
                txtUserName.Text = dr["uname"].ToString();
                            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }    
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update users Set uname=@Uname,ushortname=@Ushortname,pswd=HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pswd) where ucode=@UCODE", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", txtUserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ushortname", txtUserShortName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", LblUcode.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
```

There is no error, the data simply isn't being updated.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` code return by statement if will return 1 if it updates.. Try to Execute statement in ssms

Comment: if no error and no updation then there is something wrong in your where clause.Check that is it satisfying the where clause condition or not?

Comment: I have checked using breakpoints and the value getting in where clause is correct.

Comment: debug it and add breakpoint to query and copy the final query and run it directly in your database and see is it working or not?

Comment: Yes @yogi it is working well in sql server

Comment: @prachi `update users Set uname='test user',ushortname='tinku',pswd=HASHBYTES('MD5','testpwd') where ucode='12'` you ran this type of query in db and it worked?

Comment: Password security recommendation #1: Instead of performing the MD5 hashing of the password at the DB server, do it at the client-side (that is, in your C# code). Because right now, you are sending the password to the DB across the network (possibly over an unencrypted connection).

Comment: Password security recommendation #2: Instead of just hashing the password, [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) "see e.g. Wikipedia article") it as well.

Comment: That I will do @stakx later, but now the problem is their is no updation in data.

Comment: **1.** Show us *all* relevant code, including how & where you create `conn` (remove sensitive data from the connection string, though) and how & where you open it before you execute the query. **2.** Speaking of the connection string: Are you connecting to a full SQL Server instance, or to a (SQL Server Compact) database file? **3.** *How* do you check whether the data has been updated or not?

Comment: In which line you are opening the `Sqlconnection` conn

Comment: @prachi: That cannot possibly be your actual code, because it is syntactically invalid (and would therefore not compile nor run): You cannot have statements (the last 7 lines of code) outside of a method. -1 for repeatedly wasting everyone's time by posting misleading and/or incomplete information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update users Set uname=@Uname,ushortname=@Ushortname,pswd=HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pswd) where ucode=@UCODE ", conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", txtUserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ushortname", txtUserShortName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", UCODE);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

You are missing `@` in Ucode. Also, its a good practice to wrap your code inside `using` block check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389506/ado-net-closing-connection-when-using-using-statement).

Comment: I have that statement in my code but missed to place here

Comment: @prachi - Have you debugged your code? If it is running properly and still data is not getting updated, Please run `SQL Profiler` and check what query is actually getting executed in database.

Comment: I have debugged my code and the query is properly executing in database.

Comment: @prachi - Have you checked your profiler? What query it is issuing to database?

Comment: while debugging the textboxes shows the value which was already their and not the updated one.

Comment: On page load I have assigned values to textbox,after editing that value on form the new value does not retained and I am getting the old values which I have assigned on page load .

Comment: @prachi - Okay I agree but what I am saying is, if your code is passing correct values but then too your DB is not getting updated. You need to run SQL profiler while updating the data through APP and check what query is issued. If you don't know how to use profiler check this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff650699.aspx

Comment: @prachi - ohk..Show how you are binding the textboxes in that case.

Comment: I have updated my code please go through it,actually when I click edit button it goes to another page where through dropdown I select the uname and passed it back through querystring.

Answer (score 0):

See the edited below code:-

```
if (!PostBack)
{
   string databaseconnectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
   string sql = "update users Set uname=@Uname,ushortname=@Ushortname,pswd=HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pswd) where ucode=@UCODE";    
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(databaseconnectionstring))
   {
     conn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand())
     {
        cmd.CommandText=sql;
        cmd.Connection=databaseconnectionstring;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",txtUserName.Text );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ushortname",txtUserShortName.Text );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd",txtPassword.Text );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", UCODE);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have declared connection string in my class itself.

Comment: @prachi: see the updated code, let me know if it works or not

Comment: I have seen the code and updated as suggested but still not working @Nadeem

Comment: @NadeemKhan what made you to add `if(!ISpostBack)` in your answer ? :P

Comment: I have Used if (!IsPostBack) condition,still not working @Nadeem

Comment: @prachi `if (!IsPostBack) ` is not the solution of this. check your query in db directly and see changes

Comment: @yogi970:You need to check if(!IsPostBack). Or you will always override your data.

Comment: @prachi: See the modified code, if this doesn't work, you have to check your Database properly.

Comment: @NadeemKhan it is update query not the insert query and if it updates for first time or multiple time the result will  be same ,yes it will override the data with **same data** and she no where mentioned that she is using this code in page load. so not much sense to add post back

Comment: @yogi970: Agreed with you.!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the parameter names match exactly what they do in your sql string.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", UCODE);
```

Also, either wrap all of that in a using or try/finally to dispose of the connection.  I'm assuming you've already got code to open the connection before trying to execute it.

Comment: yes i have tried using the above statement also i.e. taking @UCODE scalar variable in
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", UCODE);

Comment: What's the exact error?  Or is it not doing anything in the update?

Comment: It is not doing anything in update.But their is no error

Comment: I can tell you that it WILL need the @UCODE in order to work eventually.  Are you sure there is a row in the table that would cause an update to occur?

Comment: Yes there is a row in table with correct UCODE value

Comment: Are you confirming this in the database or through your web app?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            string bsname = Request.QueryString["bsname"];
            string bscode = Request.QueryString["bscode"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bsname))
            {

               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBsName.Text))
               {
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from bs WHERE bscode=@bscode", conn);
                 SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                 conn.Open();
                 txtBsName.ReadOnly = false;
                 dadapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bscode", bscode));
                 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 while (dr.Read())
                 {
                    lblBsCode.Text = dr["bscode"].ToString();
                    txtBsName.Text = dr["bsname"].ToString();

                 }
                 dr.Close();
                 conn.Close();
              }
           }
       }
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           conn.Open();
           string UCODE = LblUcode.Text;
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update users Set uname=@Uname,ushortname=@Ushortname,pswd=HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pswd) where ucode=@UCODE", conn);

           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",txtUserName.Text );
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ushortname",txtUserShortName.Text );
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pswd",txtPassword.Text );
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCODE", UCODE);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cmd.Dispose();

           ShowMessage("Company Data update Successfully......!");

           clear();
}
```

Thank you all its working now with the help of above code.

Comment: Is your Update inside Page_Load or separate function

Comment: separate function actually on save button click event