# use connection with different forms c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odac

I have a form say `form1` in C# the user has to put database name username password in the textboxes of `form1`. Once the connection is established `form2` will open which will display data with predefined sqls. Also additional forms are needed to use the same connection string.How can i achieve this.
I am using `ODAC` to connect to oracle database.

This is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;


namespace Sparrow1
{
    public partial class connectform : Form
    {
        public connectform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                       
        }

        private OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + username.Text +
            ";Password=" + password.Text +
            ";Data Source=" + dataSource.Text + ";";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                button1.Enabled = false;
                statuslabel.Text = "Success";
                this.Hide();
                overviewform oviewform = new overviewform();
                oviewform.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                statuslabel.Text = "Failed";
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the `using` statement in order to close/dispose your connections properly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389506/ado-net-closing-connection-when-using-using-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a public static string variable named connectionString in Form1.cs

```
public static string connectionString
```

get its value from other forms by Form1.connectionString;

```
Form1.connectionString;
```